# 16.04 Kubuntu shut down overnight, want to find reason

Tags: shutdown

Hi I set a surveillance camera.
I plan to leave it on for 30 days in winter.
If it shuts down halfway that is a problem.
So I want to find and address the cause of a shutdown that happened overnight.
Thank you.

> gedit /var/log/kern.log.1

gave

> Nov 20 23:23:21 h170pro NetworkManager[867]:   [1479702201.2005] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound

in the last line.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?, May be an overheating problem? Exactly what shuts down? The camera or the PC?

Comment: The PC. 
I did, gedit /var/log/kern.log.1, and it ended with, Nov 20 23:23:21 h170pro NetworkManager[867]: <info>  [1479702201.2005] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound.

Comment: Ok, so, please edit your question and append the output of the logs, and any other relevant information, so we can help you better. Append also the Xorg log.

Comment: Is there other logs that might be more useful?

Comment: Yeah, try to locate some like ERROR, or WARNING, or ERR, etc. Otherwise, you could put the complete log. The last line does not show anything relevant. Other logs like Xorg.log, or another in the logs folder.

Comment: Apparently if it shut down normally they should say so in this log, and I guess I don't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, the first message logged (in `/var/log/kern.log*`) when the system comes up is `... [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset`. The number in `[` `]` is "microseconds since boot", the time the entry was logged. The entries just BEFORE this line are the last log entries the system made before it went down. Power failures may not get logged.

Comment: The one after the above output is also, Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset, for me. So I guess I can't know? No way to detect hardware failure or power outage?

Comment: Look at the several lines above the first `... [    0.000000]` line (the ones with the non-zero timestamps). They might be at the end of `/var/log/kern.log.1`.

Comment: They are all network manager related things. Don't know if they have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: I'd guess not. You seem to have a hardware problem (probably power related) that takes your system down before it can log the event. You could find out when it dies by `ping`ing it constantly.